# How to send json with curl to a url

Tags: php, json, curl

I seek in stackoverflow a possible solution but any is good for me.
I will send the next json-rpc code to another file. This file contains a bottle server.

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method":"leer_datos", "params": {"bd":"escuela","tabla":"secretaria"}}' http://localhost:8081/rpc/alchemy
```

Now, i have in a file the next code for use cURL:

```
<?php
// Get cURL resource
$curl = curl_init();
// Set some options - we are passing in a useragent too here
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://localhost:8081/rpc/alchemy',
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Codular Sample cURL Request',
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{'jsonrpc': '2.0','method':'leer_datos','params':{'bd':'escuela','tabla':'secretaria'}}"
));
// Send the request & save response to $resp
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
echo $resp;
// Close request to clear up some resources
curl_close($curl);
?>
```

I know the json is not well envoy.

How can i send the json to the url?

Sorry, my english is bad.

Comment: You send json from js? Why you crate json by yourself?

Comment: No. I need to send a json code from a php file to a python file with a bottle server. This json code contains a parameters which use the python file to do things.

Answer (score 1):

JSON data (key and value) must be only in **"double quote"**.

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method": "leer_datos",
    "params": {
        "bd": "escuela",
        "tabla": "secretaria"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. With a little modification of my last code and your clue it is solved. I can't post the answer now. Coming i will write the solution,